# Update original data frame after changing editable cells with datatable output

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the following simple shiny app which you can go ahead and run after saving as app.R.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

DF <- data.frame(x = formatC(c(1, 2, 3), width = 10), 
                 y = formatC(c(5, 4, 6), width = 5),
                 z = formatC(c(9, 5, 5), width = -5))

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton(outputId = "down", label = "Download table")
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Dataframe read in as a reactive expression
  df <- reactive({
    DF
  })
  
  
  #Output data frame as editable data table.
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(df(), editable = 'cell', rownames = F)
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  
  
  #Add download button
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("table", Sys.Date(), ".txt", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(df(), file,
                  quote = FALSE,
                  col.names = FALSE,
                  row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

First, I am making a table `DF` with very specific formatting. Go ahead and see what the output format looks like by clicking the "Download Table" button. Next in the code I make that data frame a reactive expression `df`. The app displays an editable table. If you double click any cell you can change the value of that cell, however changes are not recorded in the downloaded table because it does not update the `df` reactive expression. I want to use an `observer` function to record the cells that have changed and update the `df` or a new `reactiveVal` so that I can download the updated data with the specified format with the download handler.

Note: Using the `buttons = c('copy', 'excel')` call in the `datatable` function is not what I want to do here. If I do that I lose the formatting I originally defined for this data frame.

Goals:

1. Downloaded table captures all changes in the table from clicking the datatable and changing
   values.
2. The format spacing of the original df is maintained in the text file.

I think I will need to use `reactiveVal` but I am still kind of fuzz on these functions.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `editData` from `DT` package :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton(outputId = "down", label = "Download table")
  ),
  mainPanel(DTOutput("table"))
))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  #Dataframe read in as a reactive expression
  observe({
    rv$df  <- iris
  })
  
  
  #Output data frame as editable data table.
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(rv$df, editable = 'cell', rownames = FALSE)}, server = TRUE)
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('table')
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    print(input$table_cell_edit)
    rv$df <- editData(rv$df, input$table_cell_edit, 'table', rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  #Add download button
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("table", Sys.Date(), ".txt", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(rv$df, file,
                  quote = FALSE,
                  col.names = FALSE,
                  row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Right. But you don't need `<<-` if you use a reactive data frame.

Comment: @asaei  Thanks for your reply! This gets the values to update but the format of my original df is not maintained. If you replace the iris dataset with the original df

 `data.frame(x = formatC(c(1, 2, 3), width = 10), 
                 y = formatC(c(5, 4, 6), width = 5),
                 z = formatC(c(9, 5, 5), width = -5))`

you will see the column widths are lost after you change values. Is there any way to maintain that original format? Alternatively, is there a way to control the column widths and justification from the datatable function?

Comment: you can just add ```tab```  instead of ```space``` as the separator in  ```write.table```. ```sep = "\t"```

Comment: @asaei. Thanks for the reply. That doesn't get me what I want. Using the `formatC()` function I defined that the first column has 10 spaces as defined by the width argument and is right justified (positive width number). Column 2 has 5 spaces and column 3 has 5 spaces and the number is left justified (negative width value). There is an additional space separator between each of these columns. If you run the original shiny app I posted and hit the download button and open the text file you will see the format I am describing. Thanks!

Comment: please try ```write.fwf``` from ```gdata``` package to see if that is what you want. It is to write objects in the fixed width format.